# Check whether datetime object agrees with today in jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I would like to test whether a python datetime object agrees with today within the browser, using jinja2

Something like

```
{% if current_user.last_seen_datetime.date() == TODAY %}
```

how would I get TODAY?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be something you should be doing with a templating language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the simples solution is to add a function to the User class

```
def show_paper_suggestions(self):
    if self.last_seen_datetime is None:
        return 1
    else:
        return (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self.last_seen_datetime).days
```